# ¿Como paso array php a Jquery?

Tags: php, jquery, ajax, json

tengo un problemita:

```
<?php 
require_once '../Controlador/HuespedController.php';
$Huesped = new HuespedController;
$userdoc = '44889498'; //originalmente aqui va esto $_POST['doc'],
$consulta = $Huesped->BuscarDocumento($userdoc);// se llama a la funcion

print_r($consulta);
?>
```

Este codigo sirve muy bien el problema es que esta consulta a la bd me devuelve un array que es el siguiente:

> Array ( [0] => Array ( [clicod] => 1 [tpcli] => Principal2 [country]
>   => 51Peru [doctp] => DNI [doc] => 44889498 [docexp] => 2018-07-08 [name] => Augusto [lastname] => Pruebita [email] => Prueba@gmail.com
>   [phone] => 999569041 [address] => Urb. Villa Flores ) )

como puedo pasar esto al jquery, e intentado con $.post(), pero al darme tremendo array me resulta muy complicado, hay una manera mas efectiva de poder pasarlo?.

psdt: e visto que algunos usan Json_encode() , pero no se como utilizarlo y como pasarlo al jquery.

Muchas gracias por tomarse el tiempo de leer mi pregunta posteada, les agradezco mucho que me compartan su conocimiento.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Con una respuesta en json te queda más sencillo. Puedes hacer uso de $.post(). Yo suelo usar $.ajax() para este tipo de usos. Si deseas usar ajax, podrías hacerlo por ejemplo:

```
$.ajax({
    url: 'resultado.php',
    type: 'post',
    dataType: 'json', //faltaba la comita
    error: function () {
        alert('Se presentó un error');
    },
    success: function (data) {
        $.each(data, function (indice, valor) {
            console.log('clicod: ' + valor.clicod + ' - Indice: ' + indice);
            console.log('tpcli: ' + valor.tpcli + ' - Indice: ' + indice);
        })
    }
});
```

En tu resultado.php, puedes hacer la consulta a tu controlador como lo vienes haciendo, solo que la respuesta la tienes que devolver con json_encode:

```
<?php 
require_once '../Controlador/HuespedController.php';
$Huesped = new HuespedController;
$userdoc = '44889498'; //originalmente aqui va esto $_POST['doc'],
$consulta = $Huesped->BuscarDocumento($userdoc);// se llama a la funcion

echo json_encode($consulta);
?>
```

Si quieres mas info sobre ajax de jQuery: http://api.jquery.com/jquery.ajax/

Si necesitas conocer más sobre json: https://json.org/json-es.html

Comment: Muchas gracias María, te agradesco mucho que compartieras un poco de tu conocimiento, me sirvio de maravilla =D

Comment: Excelente Israel, un gusto poder ayudarte :)